# iwlwifi ubuntu drivers upgrade

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I'm trying to use the Intel AX211 on Ubuntu 20.04 with the latest drivers. However, when I copy the latest drivers for this chip to /lib/firmware, I consistently receive the following message:

```
[  144.790109] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: b0:dc:ef:a3:c0:9b <br>
[  144.811610] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[  555.354495] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode failed with error -2
[  555.354507] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-65.ucode failed with error -2
[  555.354802] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[  555.354814] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.25
[  555.355115] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 64.97bbee0a.0 so-a0-gf-a0-64.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[  555.385082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz, REV=0x370
[  555.535079] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded PNVM version 0x5a8dfca
[  555.547617] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x2010d000
[  555.617023] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: b0:dc:ef:a3:c0:9b
[  555.637339] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

**First question:** why this version 66 doesn't exist at https://github.com/endlessm/linux-firmware. Also, I can't seem to force it to use a newer version with a higher number (7x). To test this, I executed `mv iwlwifi-so-a0-gf* _old/` and copied the file from the repository. But then, I received the following notifications:

```
[  639.807608] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807617] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-65.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807629] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-64.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807637] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807644] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-62.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-61.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-60.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807668] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807674] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-58.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807681] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807689] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807695] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807702] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807710] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807716] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807723] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807728] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807735] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807742] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807748] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807755] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807773] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807780] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807787] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807794] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807801] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807807] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807814] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[  639.807815] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[  639.807817] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-39
[  639.807819] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-66
[  639.807819] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

I'm wondering how I can force the loading of these newer drivers (e.g., iwlwifi-so-a00-gf-a0-7x), either by increasing the maximum version supported or through some other method.

Comment: I am quite confident that you'll have much better luck with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: The 6.2 kernel in 22.04 will allow firmware version 72 to load

Comment: What if I had to have Ubuntu 20.04 due to some legacy code ?

Comment: Legacy operating system and its legacy driver do not lead to latest drivers and firmware. If you haven't any performance issue, I'd ignore it.